# When yarn starts for remote debugging, I have encountered the follow error?

Tags: java, eclipse, remote-debugging, hadoop-yarn

I have yarn cluster with two virtual machine. And I want to remote debugging with eclipse. And I add this code block in yarn-env.sh

```
YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=9999"
```

When yarn starts for remote debugging, I have encountered the following error,

```
master: ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
master: ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
master: JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below vmargument is working in commen

-vmargs -Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=2020,server=y,suspend=n